# Statistical analysis for questionnaire with levels and how to do it in r?

Tags: r, survey

I have this questionnaire.

Where people are asked about the importance of eating vegetables in their life, using a likert scale for level questions, and cathegorical questions coded with numbers.

A quick summary of the questionnaire would be like this:

```
Q1: Consuming vegetables in your diet is a priority for you?
1– Not a priority
2– Low priority
3– Medium priority
4– High priority
5– Essential 

Q2:What kind of area do you live?

1- Rural area
2- Urban area

Q3:What education have you completed?
1- None
2- elementary
3- middle
4- High
5- University

Q4: Is eating organic vegetables a priority for you?
1– It is not a priority
2– Low priority
3– Medium priority
4– High priority
5– Essential
```

There are more questions obviously but in essence the questionnaire is this way

So a few lines of the dataframe of questions looks like this:

```
Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
1   1   1   1
5   2   4   4
2   2   2   2
```

and i have another dataframe coded with words and numbers

```
Q1  Q2       Q3         Q4
1   rural   none        1
5   urban   high        4
2   urban   elementary  2
```

So...
The idea is to find an association between the level of response and different categories that exist in the questions.

But I can't think of what statistic to use and how to do it in, specially in R.(correlation?, fisher exact test?how to manage dataframe in r and stuff)

I would appreciate a lot if you guide me please 'cause i really need help

Comment: Not really a coding question so voting to migrate to Cross Validated where the stats experts are.

Comment: How much statistics have you taken?  If you don't understand the math, the tools (R, etc) cannot help you.  If you do, you can probably figure out how to do this from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing to do is make sure that the ones coded with words are recoded with numbers, and that you note which number equals which response. The question is, are you interested in a particular outcome variable? Because then you could run a regression and transform the categorical variables into dummies while dropping a baseline level. If you just look at correlations between responses, you still have the unknown of whether other responses are affecting that correlation and therefore cannot make any definitive conclusions, which is in the end less informative.